# The Killer or The Truth?

Tags: gunpoint

Danger: spoilers ahead!

---

So I've reached a stage where I need to choose either The Killer (side with Rooke) or The Truth (side with Jackson). What are the implications of my choice? Is it just one mission or does the game change completely at the point and I'd need to play it again?

Will appreciate answers with minimal spoilers.

Comment: Knowing nothing about this game and having no desire to play this, I looked into it.  Seems like a final decision scenario where you pick one, play another level or two, and reach the end of the game.  It's likely they lead to different endings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm gonna keep this as spoiler-free as I can:

The mission set Killer/Truth is shortly prior to the ending. The ending itself, however, is only affected in minor detail by the choice you make there, with a story difference along the lines of the early (Intex-related) decision (read: basically nothing, but the characters will act slightly differently)

So: Don't fret, choose what you wish to choose and experience the story - and the epilogue.